# How to add text to a graph in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy.stats

I am trying to add text inside the below graph using figtext() but the written code below does not work. I appreciate any help. [image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
x = np.array([0.00161, 0.00322, 0.00483, 0.00645, 0.00806])
y = np.array([0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.013])

a, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
slope = round(slope, 4)
intercept = round(intercept, 4)
r_value = r_value
r_squared = round(r_value ** 2, 4)

plt.scatter(x, y, color='purple')
plt.figtext(-25, 25, f"y={slope}x+{intercept}")
plt.figtext(-25, 25, f"R^2={r_squared}")
plt.text(1, 17, 'y = ' + '{:.2f}'.format(b) + ' + {:.2f}'.format(a) + 'x', size=14)
plt.xlabel("Concentration")
plt.ylabel("Absorbance")
plt.title("Phosphorus Calibration Curve")
plt.plot(x, a*x+b, color='steelblue', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try reading the [`figtext`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figtext.html) docs first, specifically around what the `x` and `y` parameters expect? The same goes for `plt.text`.

Comment: `ax = plt.gca()` and `ax.text(...)` is probably more adequate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as I think, is in *x* and *y* coordinates that you used.

Coordinates in *plt.figtext* (without transformation) are in **figure**
coordinates, i.e. floats between *0* and *1*.
This detail looks another way in *plt.text*, where the default is
**data** coordinates.

In my opinion, you should not "mix" both methods.

Using **figure** coordinates and calls only to *plt.figtext* I changed your
drawing code to:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, color='purple')
plt.xlabel('Concentration')
plt.ylabel('Absorbance')
plt.title('Phosphorus Calibration Curve')
plt.plot(x, a * x + b, color='steelblue', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
plt.figtext(0.15, 0.83, f'y = {slope}x + {intercept}')
plt.figtext(0.15, 0.77, f'R^2 = {r_squared}')
plt.figtext(0.15, 0.7,  f'y = {b:.4f} + {a:.4f}x', size=14)
plt.show()
```

getting:

[image]

Adjust the above coordinates any way you wish.

But if you want use *plt.text*, use **data** coordinates.
E.g. change the last *plt.figtext* to

```
plt.text(0.0015, 0.0112,  f'y = {b:.4f} + {a:.4f}x', size=14)
```

and you will get similar result.